# Touchable Opacity make my button disapear

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I want to make some image as button so i import the image inside a View and then i put an Touchable Opacity on the image but. I don't know why the touchable opacity makes my image disapear or move. I did it in previous pages and i didn't have the problem.[Styles of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H7bW.jpg) [without TO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6FVT.jpg) [With TO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xUJ6.jpg)

Comment: This is too broad to really understand. Is there any chance you could define your problem more specifically?

Comment: Sure. There is more explaination down below with a full screenshot

Comment: Please, never put images of code, as it's not possible to us to copy/paste it for testing, they are not searchable so the question will never appear to a user that has the same problem.    Last thing, instead of adding an answer to you question, edit your original question adding the info you want to add

Answer (score 1):

Try this Style

```
hamburger:{
  left:20,
  height:30,
  width:30,
}
```

Use resize mode like this

```
<Image resizeMode="contain" />
```

Comment: If i use these kind of numbers the button will not be places at the same place on every phone right ?

Comment: yes but if you use '100%' height it sets in full screens so use some static value and check it.

Answer (score 0):

More details here. 
So this is my screen right now. [Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSAiA.jpg)

The two images, the gear and the 3 bars (that i call hamburger) i want to make them as buttons so a side menu appear when clickin on them. So i just create the image and i want to put a touchable opacity on top of it so when you touch the button it shows that it works. 
But the problem is that when i add in the code the TouchableOpacity> /TouchableOpacity> around my Image/>, The image itself disapear as you can see on the first screenshots. The only thing i change in the code is adding the TouchableOpacity to the image and this occurs.